# Do not allow decimal and alphabet values in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to restict decimal and alphabatic values in textbox. I just want to enter only numbers in textbox. And do not copy and paste th text and decimal value also. Want t enter only numbers(0 o 9). How can I do this using regex of javascript o jquery.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44pc78pj/175/)

See this fiddle, here everything is working. But arrow keys are not working. I can't able to move left and right, and if I give (shift+home) or (shift + end) its not selecting the value. Please help me for

```js
 

 $(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {    
           $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
            if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

```html
 
    
 <span>Int</span>
<input type="text" name="numeric" class='allownumericwithoutdecimal'>
<div>Numeric values only allowed  (Without Decimal Point) </div>
```

do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
$(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur paste", function(event) {
    var that = this;

    //paste event 
    if (event.type === "paste") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(that).val($(that).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
        }, 100);
    } else {

        if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Int</span>
<input type="text" name="numeric" class='allownumericwithoutdecimal'>
<div>Numeric values only allowed  (Without Decimal Point) </div>
```

Comment: If copy and paste Text or decimal value , it is taking. I dont want to copy paste text and decimal value. If copy paste also i want to do only numbers

Comment: Please check in fiddle once. If I paste " 555.55" , it is removing only decimal point and show the value as "55555".

Comment: Here I want to allow only one negative symbal. It should allow negative value also... Please help me for this.

Comment: use this regex [^(-?\d{1,})].+

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/44pc78pj/183/     Look at this fiddle...If i use this regex also its not woking. Please check once am I added regex correctly?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me the answer for this

Comment: event.which for "-" is 45 so you have to update the if block  (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)  , here a demo http://jsfiddle.net/348au7jz/

Comment: Thanku so much Vladu Ionut. But negative symbol should be in starting only like ("-2250"). But it is allowing middle also like("22-50"). And If I copy paste it is allowing decimal value also. Can you please help me for this only.

Comment: How can I do this. Vladu Ionut please help me for doing this.

Comment: https://github.com/lockevn/html-numeric-input take a look on that link you need small improvent

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  /* Allow digits only */
  $("#wdm_num").keypress(function (e) {
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        $("#wdm_errmsg").html("Please Enter Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
   /* Do not allow paste */
   $('#wdm_num').bind("paste",function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="wdm_num" id="wdm_num" />&nbsp;<span id="wdm_errmsg"></span>
```

Comment: I want to do copy and paste also. But only numbers. Not decimals and not not characters.